# Trying to find the true width of an image using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the "true" width of images using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function( ) {
   $('.pageContent img').each(function(){
        var theImage = new Image();
        theImage.src = $(this).attr("src");
        var imageWidth = theImage.width;
        console.log(imageWidth);
   }
}
```

The problem I'm getting is each time I reload the page the results are different. Some imageWidth are 0. Any idea why this would happen please?

This is using Jquery 1.9.1 and Chrome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Some imageWidth are 0.
```

Reason is you are calculating the width before its rendering to the DOM.

Use `onLoad` method instead.So that you will get the exact image ,because its already added to the `DOM`

```
$(window).load(function( ) {
  ----------calculations goes here
}
```

Comment: @ebramtharwat it is called when DOM is ready, not when all images are loaded

Comment: @ebramtharwat please have a look here http://api.jquery.com/category/events/document-loading/

Comment: @user1001421 Glad to help you out :)

Comment: PS. I will flag is as answered as soon as stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: @user1001421 No issues,have a great time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using window.load (*the callback will be called after all your images are loaded*)

```
$(window).load(function( ) {
   $('.pageContent img').each(function(){
        var theImage = new Image();
        theImage.src = $(this).attr("src");
        var imageWidth = theImage.width;
        console.log(imageWidth);
   }
}
```